# nested for loop python of two lists to produce list to go into panda dataframe table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

I have two lists:  SoapName and SoapPrices as follows each containing 16 elements:

SoapName

```
[{'title': 'Beer and Honey Shampoo bar'},
 {'title': 'Cedarwood Shaving Soap'},
 {'title': 'Chamomile and Lavender Shampoo and Body Bar'}...]
```

SoapPrices

```
[{'price': 6.0},
 {'price': 5.0},
 {'price': 5.0}...]
```

I would like to create a table in the following format so that I can insert it into a `pandas` dataframe table:

```
{'title': 'Beer and Honey Shampoo bar', 'price': 6.0}
{'title': 'Cedarwood Shaving Soap', 'price': 5.0}
{'title': 'Chamomile and Lavender Shampoo and Body Bar', 'price': 5.0}....
```

So far I have gone back to first principles using `BeautifulSoup` to web scrape the data and tried to do a nested loop:

```
all_soap = []

soapinformation = soup.find_all("h1", class_= "product_title entry-title elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default")

for soap in soapinformation:
    soapTitle = soap.find("a").text
    soapInfo = {"title" : soapTitle, "price" : price3[0-17]}
    print(soapInfo)
```

the output being:

```
{'title': 'Beer and Honey Shampoo bar', 'price': '6.00'}
{'title': 'Cedarwood Shaving Soap', 'price': '6.00'}
{'title': 'Chamomile and Lavender Shampoo and Body Bar', 'price': '6.00'}....
```

I'm not sure how to iterate the data for price.

Comment: just using `float(price3[0-17])` into the dict?

Answer (score 0):

`zip` names and prices and then create a new dict for each pair of name and price:

```
[{**name, **price} for name, price in zip(names, prices)]

#[{'title': 'Beer and Honey Shampoo bar', 'price': 6.0}, 
# {'title': 'Cedarwood Shaving Soap', 'price': 5.0}, 
# {'title': 'Chamomile and Lavender Shampoo and Body Bar', 'price': 5.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to answer of @Psidom - Try to avoid working with a bunch of lists, cause you can control its length only with difficulty, if there are elements not available.

Change your strategy collecting your data, you could get the infos in one go.

```
for e in soup.select('article'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h1.text,
        'price':e.bdi.span.next_sibling,
        'url':e.a.get('href')
    })
```

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/'
req = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
data = []
for e in soup.select('article'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h1.text,
        'price':e.bdi.span.next_sibling,
        'url':e.a.get('href')
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

| title | price | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Beer and Honey Shampoo bar | 6.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/beer-and-honey-shampoo-bar/ |
| Cedarwood Shaving Soap | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/cedarwood-shaving-soap/ |
| Chamomile and Lavender Shampoo and Body Bar | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/chamomile-and-lavender-shampoo-and-body-bar/ |
| Fir Needle and Mint Shampoo and Body Bar | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/fir-needle-and-mint-shampoo-and-body-bar/ |
| Mint Chocolate Face and Body Bar | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/mint-chocolate-face-and-body-bar/ |
| Mint Chocolate Face and Body Bar- Vegan | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/mint-chocolate-face-and-body-bar-vegan/ |
| Orange and Honey Shampoo and Body Bar | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/orange-and-honey-shampoo-and-body-bar/ |
| Rosemary, Lemongrass and Lavender Face and Body Bar | 5.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/rosemary-lemongrass-lavender-face-body-bar/ |
| Body Butter - Butter Up & Settle Down | 7.00 | https://ratherlather.co.uk/shop/body-butter-butter-up-settle-down/ |

...